# Why does a power trip "disable" internet connectivity?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco, router, adsl, electrical-power

At home, we've set up a server with Windows Server 2008 R2. This server provides DNS, DHCP and a number of other services for the network.

We have a Cisco Router (not sure about model) that manages static IP addresses required for business purposes (until the ADSL line gets installed at the office) and also links us to the internet. Please note that I have a very limited understanding of how the network infrastructure is set up, so details might be incorrect.

Basically, what I've been told is that network traffic from my pc to the net looks something like `My computer > Windows Server > Cisco router > ADSL router > intenet`

There's a few problems with the electrics in the house, and if, for instance, I turn my heater on at the wrong time, the breaker overloads and the whole house loses power. When we turn the power back on, the Cisco router indicates that we have internet connectivity, but the server reports Local Only access.

Whats more is that, should the power trip again while the server is reporting Local Only access, when it comes back up after the 2nd power trip, internet connectivity is restored and everything works as it should.

Can anyone explain this? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain the issue at hand, but I have another recommendation: Run and get a good UPS. You risk damage to your hardware, and with an UPS you have both surge protection and can keep the system running during short outages.

Comment: A UPS is a permanent solution to a temporary problem. Once the ADSL line gets installed at the office, then the server and Cisco router is going to be removed and put there. At that point, we'll just have the wireless router and the wired switch. I just wanted to know why a 2nd power outage would correct the internet connectivity issue.

Comment: Well, my recommendation for a UPS is global, meaning you'll *need* one in the final setup as well (IMHO). Also, I consider it very risky to run this hardware in your environment, as any single circuit break can kill your devices. For me an UPS would be an integral part of this temporary fix. And sorry I can't comment on your real question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting any of the devices on a UPS?

Comment: We don't have any UPS to use at this point, please see my comment on SvenW's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the win2k8 server alone, does it eventually report full connectivity?

If you unplug + replug the Ethernet connection to the server when it's reporting "no connectivity", (after everything's powered up) does it still report "no connectivity" ?

We deploy a portable server for one of our products, and the issue that comes up now and then is the clients not getting IP @ startup.  This is usually due to having started and connected the windows client to the network prior to starting the server -- they won't get IP unless we force a DHCP renew, or we wait a few minutes. Your server is probably not using DHCP to obtain it's address, but windows may be performing the 'connectivity' test before the Cisco is fully up?  Pulling the cable and re-connecting it makes windows sense a loss of signal, and will re-initialize the connection (and probably the connectivity check)

Comment: Interesting theory, but if that were the case, why does win2k8 report full connectivity after the 2nd outage? Surely if this is what's actually happening, then the 2nd outage wouldn't make any improvement?